# Reacting to Task completion: `.ContinueWith()` vs `GetAwaiter().OnCompleted()`

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library, continuations

Say I have a [`Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) that generates an `int`, and a callback that *accepts* an `int`:

```cs
Task<int> task = ...;
Action<int> f = ...;
```

Now I want to set it up so that once the task has completed and returned its integer result, the callfack `f` will be called with that integer – without requiring the main thread to wait for the task to complete:

1. As I understand it, the typical solution for this is the [`Task.ContinueWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

   ```cs
   task.ContinueWith(t => f(t.Result));
   ```
2. However, one could also get a [`TaskAwaiter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.taskawaiter(v=vs.110).aspx) for the task, and use its event-like interface:

   ```cs
   TaskAwaiter<int> awaiter = task.GetAwaiter();
   awaiter.OnCompleted(() => f(awaiter.GetResult()));
   ```

Now, I realize that `TaskAwaiter` is not intended for common use in application code, and mainly exists to be used internally by the `await` keyword.
But in order to deepen my understanding of the TPL, I'm wondering:

**Is there any practical difference between solutions (1) and (2)?**

For example,

- ...regarding on which thread the callback will be invoked?
- ...regarding what happens when an exception is thrown in the task or callback?
- ...any other side-effects?

Comment: 2 is simply the generalized version of 1 that works with multiple awaitable types...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One difference is that

```
task.ContinueWith(t => f(t.Result));
```

will not capture current synchronization context, and in, for example, UI applications - callback will be executed on thread pool thread. While

```
TaskAwaiter<int> awaiter = task.GetAwaiter();
awaiter.OnCompleted(() => f(awaiter.GetResult()));
```

will capture synchronization context, and callback will be executed on UI thread.

Of course you can do the same with `ContinueWith`:

```
task.ContinueWith(r => f(r.Result), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

But that's not what you used in question. So ways provided in your question are different at least in that regard.

There is also a difference in exception representation, accessing `Task.Result` if task has faulted will throw `AggregateException` (with one or more exceptions as inner exceptions), while accessing `awaiter.GetResult()` will not wrap thrown exception in `AggregateException` and will rethrow it as is (and if there were multiple exceptions, like from `Task.WhenAll` - all except one will be ignored and just one will be thrown).